# Trouble installing numpy 1.11.0 onto python 3.7.16 virtual environment

Tags: numpy, pycharm, virtualenv

I'm using the PyCharm terminal. My specific python is 3.7.16, and I'm pip installing rather than conda.

> Collecting numpy==1.11.0
> Using cached numpy-1.11.0.zip (4.7 MB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
> Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
> Building wheel for numpy (setup.py) ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
> exit code: 1
> [232 lines of output]
> Running from numpy source directory.
> blas_opt_info:
> blas_mkl_info:
> libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> openblas_info:
> libraries openblas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
> libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_blas_info:
> libraries satlas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_blas_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
> libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_blas_info:
> libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1640: UserWarning:
> Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
> Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
> the ATLAS environment variable.
> warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.**doc**)
> blas_info:
> libraries blas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1649: UserWarning:
> Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
> Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
> the BLAS environment variable.
> warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.**doc**)
> blas_src_info:
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1652: UserWarning:
> Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
> Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
> the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
> warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.**doc**)
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> ```
>
> operable program or batch file.
> non-existing path in 'numpy\distutils': 'site.cfg'
> 'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> F2PY Version 2
> lapack_opt_info:
> openblas_lapack_info:
> libraries openblas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> lapack_mkl_info:
> mkl_info:
> libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
> libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_info:
> libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
> libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_info:
> libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1542: UserWarning:
> Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
> Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
> the ATLAS environment variable.
> warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.**doc**)
> lapack_info:
> libraries lapack not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1553: UserWarning:
> Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
> Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
> the LAPACK environment variable.
> warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.**doc**)
> lapack_src_info:
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1556: UserWarning:
> Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
> Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
> the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
> warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.**doc**)
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
> warnings.warn(msg)
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running config_cc
> unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
> running config_fc
> unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
> running build_src
> build_src
> building py_modules sources
> creating build
> creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7
> creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy
> creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\distutils
> building library "npymath" sources
> No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
> customize GnuFCompiler
> Could not locate executable g77
> .
> .
> .
> Could not locate executable efc
> don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
> C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils_msvccompiler.py:535: UserWarning: Fallback spawn triggered. Please update distutils monkeypatch.
> warnings.warn("Fallback spawn triggered. Please update distutils monkeypatch.")
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -
> Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -I"C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\include" -I"C:\Users********\Anaconda3\envs**************\include" -I"C:\Users********\Anaconda3
> \envs**************\Include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\incl
> ude" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)
>
> Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_configtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj
> Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=1 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Ent
> erprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64 /LIBPATH:C:
> \Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64 _configtest.obj /OUT:_configtest.exe
> Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe
> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Files.obj'
> failure.
> removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 36, in 
> File "", line 34, in 
> File "C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\setup.py", line 386, in 
> setup_package()
> .
> .
> .
> File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 654, in get_mathlib_info
> raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
> RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
> Running setup.py clean for numpy
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
> exit code: 1
> [10 lines of output]
> Running from numpy source directory.
>
> ```
>   `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
>
>     - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
>     - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
> ```
>
> files that aren't checked into the git repo)
>
> Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
>
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
> Failed to build numpy
> Installing collected packages: numpy
> Attempting uninstall: numpy
> Found existing installation: numpy 1.16.4
> Uninstalling numpy-1.16.4:
> Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.16.4
> Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> Running setup.py install for numpy did not run successfully.
> exit code: 1
> [243 lines of output]
> Running from numpy source directory.
>
> Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
> with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
>
> ```
>     - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
> ```
>
> release)
> - `pip install numpy`   (last Numpy release on PyPi)
>
> blas_opt_info:
> blas_mkl_info:
> libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> openblas_info:
> libraries openblas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
> libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_blas_info:
> libraries satlas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_blas_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
> libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_blas_info:
> libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1640: UserWarning:
> Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
> Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
> the ATLAS environment variable.
> warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.**doc**)
> blas_info:
> libraries blas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1649: UserWarning:
> Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
> Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
> the BLAS environment variable.
> warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.**doc**)
> blas_src_info:
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1652: UserWarning:
> Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
> Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
> the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
> warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.**doc**)
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> ```
>
> operable program or batch file.
> non-existing path in 'numpy\distutils': 'site.cfg'
> 'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> F2PY Version 2
> lapack_opt_info:
> openblas_lapack_info:
> libraries openblas not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> lapack_mkl_info:
> mkl_info:
> libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
> libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_info:
> libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
> libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_info:
> libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib
> libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:
> libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1542: UserWarning:
> Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
> Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
> the ATLAS environment variable.
> warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.**doc**)
> lapack_info:
> libraries lapack not found in ['C:\Users\********\Desktop\VIP\**************\venv\lib', 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1553: UserWarning:
> Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
> Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
> the LAPACK environment variable.
> warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.**doc**)
> lapack_src_info:
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1556: UserWarning:
> Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
> Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
> the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
> warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.**doc**)
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
> warnings.warn(msg)
> running install
> C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
> setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
> running build
> running config_cc
> unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
> running config_fc
> unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
> running build_src
> build_src
> building py_modules sources
> building library "npymath" sources
> No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
> customize GnuFCompiler
> Could not locate executable g77
> .
> .
> .
> Could not locate executable efc
> don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
> C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils_msvccompiler.py:535: UserWarning: Fallback spawn triggered. Please update distutils monkeypatch.
> warnings.warn("Fallback spawn triggered. Please update distutils monkeypatch.")
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -
> Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -I"C:\Users********\Desktop\VIP**************\venv\include" -I"C:\Users********\Anaconda3\envs**************\include" -I"C:\Users********\Anaconda3
> \envs**************\Include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\incl
> ude" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)
>
> Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_configtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj
> Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=1 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Ent
> erprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64 /LIBPATH:C:
> \Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64 _configtest.obj /OUT:_configtest.exe
> Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe
> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Files.obj'
> failure.
> removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 36, in 
> File "", line 34, in 
> File "C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl2uig6l\numpy_f1126fe879f5464995a4306e18c2b180\setup.py", line 386, in 
> setup_package()
> .
> .
> .
> .
> File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 654, in get_mathlib_info
> raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
> RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> Rolling back uninstall of numpy
> Moving to c:\users********\desktop\vip**************\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.16.4.dist-info
>
> from c:\users********\desktop\vip**************\venv\lib\site-packages~umpy-1.16.4.dist-info
> Moving to c:\users********\desktop\vip**************\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy
>
> from c:\users********\desktop\vip**************\venv\lib\site-packages~umpy
> Moving to c:\users********\desktop\vip**************\venv\scripts\f2py.exe
> from C:\Users*****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-gk6610ht\f2py.exe
> error: legacy-install-failure
>
> Encountered error while trying to install package.
> numpy
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: `numpy==1.11.0` [doesn't provide binary wheels](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.11.0/#files) for Python 3.7 so `pip` tries to [compile from sources](https://numpy.org/install/#numpy-packages--accelerated-linear-algebra-libraries) and it's very hard and requires a lot of C/C++ dependencies. Relax the `numpy` version to just install `numpy` or limit version to one that has precompiled wheels for Python 3.7.

Comment: @phd thank you for responding! I had to go a super round about way, but this is good to know for future issues.